# How to make Docker application public accessible

Tags: docker, portforwarding

I have one web application (web2, deployed on tomcat) running on docker host.

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376

docker port web2
8000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8000
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Now, I access this application :
http://192.168.59.103:8080/analytics/index.htm

I have done the port forwarding (verizon router) :

HTTP 
TCP Any -> 80

And this mapping is against my laptop on which server is running.

**Problem**: I am not able to access this application using my public IP

http://my-public-ip:8080/analytics/index.htm

Can someone please help me this or provide pointers,where i can do some read up on this?

Thanks in advance. 
Roy

Comment: Port forwarding looks fishy.  A proper port forwarding setting shows a single port at the public IP routed to a single port at a private IP.  As docker is involved, fixing the hardware router port forwarding is only part of a solution.  For the docker side, I prefer to use [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) to cause the docker container to obtain use a preallocated private IP.  Then the hardware router is used to forward to that private IP.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, which is using Virtualbox with Docker, the missing element was I needed to add a Port Forwarding rule to Virtualbox.

See: [Cannot browse dockerized web app from other computers on network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443922/cannot-browse-dockerized-web-app-from-other-computers-on-network)